# How to get a derived class to inherit a variable from the base class to have a different value?

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, picturebox

I have a simple game in which clicking an image moving through an array of picture boxes grants the player a point and I plan to add another image to this so that a sub class grants the user a different amount of points when clicking on a different image. 
I'm wondering how to get a derived class to inherit a variable that is in the base class and change the numeric value.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
 public class Monster
 {
    public static int Score = 1;
    public Monster()
    {

    }

 }

 class Skeleton:Monster         
 {
    public Skeleton()
    {
        Score = 2;
    }

 }


public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    PictureBox[] boxes;
    int initialscore = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void boxes_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 27; x++)
        {
            if (sender.Equals(boxes[x]))
            {
                Image grass = Image.FromFile("swamp.png");
                PictureBox temp = (PictureBox)sender;
                temp.Image = grass;
            }
            if (sender.Equals(boxes[x]))
            {
                PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
                if (pb.Tag == "skeleton.png")
                {
                    addScore(Monster.Score);
                }
            }
        }

        label1.Text = " Score: " +initialscore.ToString();  
    }
    public void addScore(int add)
    {
        initialscore += add;
        label1.Text = " Score: " + initialscore.ToString();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        addScore(0);
    }
}
```

How would I get the skeleton class to be able to have a different Score value to that of the Monster class? Would anything else need to be added/changed regarding Form1, and if so what would need to be done to maintain a working score system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public class Monster
{
    public Monster()
    {
        this.Score = 1;
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Skeleton : Monster
{
    public Skeleton()
        : base()
    {
        this.Score = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property. It underlines the brackets this part: addScore(Skeleton.Score); I am not sure how to do this, could you help me create the simple object to satisfy this or is there another way in which I can still use the public static score?

Comment: You need to create instances of Monster and Skelton and use those, not operate on the static class. Read about the difference between static and instance methods/fields/properties etc. Basically: Monster myMonster = new Monster(); myMonster.Score = 3; etc.